# Oracle Reports REP-0820: Cannot import specified image

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, report, oraclereports

I want to insert an image to my report. When I choose `Insert -> Image -> Browse -> Choose the image -> OK`, I get

> "REP-0820: Cannot import specified image" error.

Image size 277 KB. I can insert other images ( even images that have bigger size ). I tried to copy my image and to insert it, opening it in paint then saving it again by doing "save as" and to insert it but they don't work. Probably my image is corrupted but I can't change it ( it came from my customer and she doesn't change it ).
 If the image is absolutely corrupted, how can I fix it? If is there other possibilities, what else can i check?

Comment: What is file name? Does it contain spaces? It shouldn't.

Comment: "aaa.jpg" No spaces.

Comment: Try to crop the image - open it, select its inner part (leave e.g. 1mm margin) and crop it. Save, try to import.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it did. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK then, better to have it here than as a comment; might help someone in the future.

---

In this case, it helped if the image was slightly **cropped**, removing a small margin which didn't affect the image but let Reports import it.

---

What didn't help was:

- opening the image in editor and performing "Save As ..." operation, but without previously editing the image
- file name didn't have spaces in it, so - that wasn't the cause